# Find the count of similar elements in two equal-sized arrays using HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I wrote code for finding the count of common elements occurring in two arrays, but my output only gives me the size of the array that I declared. Could anyone please point out the error in my code?

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

 public class arreq1 {
     public static void main(String args[]){
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
         //int t = in.nextInt();
         int n = in.nextInt();
         int p[] =new int[n]; 
         int c[] =new int[n];
         int count=0;
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
             p[i] = in.nextInt();
         for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
             c[k] = in.nextInt();
         }
         for(int j=0;j<p.length;j++){
             hm.put(p[j],j);
             if(hm.containsKey(c[j]));
             count++;
         }
         System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra semicolon at the end of the `if(hm...)` line. Otherwise the if statement just controls the execution of the empty statement `;` and not the `count++;` on the following line.

Also, you must split the last for loop into two separate loops, otherwise it will find part of the common elements. For example when j=0 it will only increment count if `c[0] == p[0]` and not if `c[0] == any p[0 .. n-1]`.

Some other improvements: You could use HashSet instead of HashMap. And you could also use other java collections utilities to do the hard work for you, example (untested):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class arreq1 {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Set<Integer> ps = new HashSet<Integer>();
    List<Integer> cl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //int t = in.nextInt();
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int p[] =new int[n]; 
    int c[] =new int[n];
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      p[i] = in.nextInt();
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
      c[k] = in.nextInt();
    }
    for(int j=0;j<p.length;j++){
      ps.add(p[j]);
      cl.add(c[j]);
    }
    // remove entries in cl that do not exist in ps
    cl.retainAll(ps);
    count = cl.size();
    System.out.println(count);
  }
}
```

Comment: found that semicolon mistake and felt very silly myself. thank you so much nonetheless :)